# How to comment a GPX file?

Tags: comments, gpx

How I can make a comment in a GPX files?

I checked on Google and here with no luck. Thank you !

Comment: `<!-- This is a comment --> `

Answer (score 7):

Assuming GPX = GPS eXchange Format it's just XML so a standard XML comment is all you'd need:

```
<!-- XML Comment -->
```

Comment: That's a very different type of comment

Answer (score 2):

Waypoint, Routes and Tracks in Gpx have a formal tag `<cmt />` and `<desc />` The other main types have something called `<extensions />` that allow you to add whatever content you want. The only requirement is that what you put in there is linked to a different schema so you can't use the default namespace for your tags.

You can put something like `<myns:cmt>Comment here</myns:cmt>` in there assuming you define the myns namespace in the top.

- You can read more about this in the Gpx specs [here](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_extensionsType)
- Garmin uses extensions extensively. To get an idea how they do it you can get their schema [here](http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd)